# SEPIC converter working in BURST mode without having one

Tags: dc-dc-converter, feedback, sepic

I designed a SEPIC using the LT3467 with coupled inductors. It supply 17V starting from a 12V input.
On the simulator (LTSPICE) everything works, but on the test board there is a problem.
With 70mA output current there is a ripple of 1V (see pic attached) caused by the wrong regulation of the chip.

[image: Output node ripple]

It seems that the regulator is working on burst mode, and that is the the cause of all my problems.
Here it is a pic of the switching node.
[image: Switching node]

Do you have any idea on how can i make the switching node switch regularly?
Maybe there is  a problem on the feedback loop.
I cannot post the pic of the schematic because i don't have enough reputation points, so if you need it you can tell me another way to post it.

Here is the schematic:
[image]

In the  link below you can find the schematic and the output node and the switching node with 200mA at the output.

Comment: What happens with load currents larger than 70mA?

Comment: I haven't test it yet, but as soon as I can I will

Comment: For proper answers without guessing, include the schematic! Draw a schematic using the tool or make it available somewhere (like google drive) and include the link then someone can add it in.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0Bx5pGK4FZRBpZVczLU92bzJ4dVk?usp=sharing

In the  link you can find the schematic and the output node and the switching node with 200mA at the output.

Comment: I added the schematic to your post for you